# Particles are not being generated from particles.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, particles.js

I have been trying to implement particles.js into my website however there were no particles being generated. So I downloaded the demo from the [github page](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js) and just opened index.html but it still doesn't generate particles. What could be the issue? If I go to the [sample site](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/), particles are generated there perfectly fine.

Here is index.html:

```
<body>
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <!-- Hero -->
  <div class="hero">
    <ul class="fly-in-header hidden">
      <li>TIRTH </li>
      <li>THE </li>
      <li>ARTIST</li>
    </ul>
    <b1>
      <a href="photography.html"><button type="button" id="main-button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">photography</button></a>

      <a href="projects.html"><button type="button" id="main-button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">projects</button></a>
    </b1>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/particles.js"></script>
  <script src="js/apps.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.hero > .fly-in-header').removeClass('hidden');
      }, 500);
    })();

  </script>
</body>
```

apps.js:

```
 particlesJS.load('particles-js',
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#000000"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#000000",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 100,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
}

);
```

Comment: Hello, Tirth. There is no way we can help you without more detail. What have you tried? Can you collect any error ou something similar and increment your question with it?
You should always take into account that questions need to be well formulated for others to be able to research an answer and try to help you

Comment: Well my code is perfectly formatted from what is shown on the github page. I have also watched youtube videos and my implementation is no different. I even downloaded the sample project from the github and opened the page included in the sample project and it still didnt work. Could there be an issue on the host end? @D.Melo

Comment: Questions should include the essential information, including the relevant code. Hyperlinks to other sites do not count. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @trincot I am getting the following error: particles.js:1539 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/tirth/Desktop/site/[object%20Object]. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Well that error explains it all. Google "cross origin requests" if you don't understand the error message. In copying the code, you moved a http: based web application to a local one. But there the ajax code won't work. You need to host it on a web server. You could get around it if you put the target url of the ajax call in the same folder as the page that calls it, editing the call itself also to point to the correct file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using localhost instead of opening the file.